# Possible to keep file path across post backs with the FileUpload control?

Tags: .net, asp.net, file-upload, postback

I have a situation where I want a user to select a file, then select an option from a DropDownList.

When they select an item from the DropDownList I do an auto post back and do some stuff with the file, but this causes the path to clear out.  Is there some way that I can keep the path from clearing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is impossible for security reason. There is no way to modify contents of file uploader by javascript or something like that. Only thing I can suggest is having a label on page which will show the file path from the last postback.

Comment: Can you even get the file path from the control?  I did a little poking around and it looks like that is restricted too...

Comment: You can get only File name without path. On some old browser full path was sent to the server but now almost all of them send only file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the path in the input hidden, and every postback or change the value on .fileupload you can update the some input. It's just a possibility.
Best Regards